# guardar datagridview y textbox en BD sql c#

Tags: c#, sql

Buenas tengo un problema al querer guardar los datos de un datagridview a una tabla en SQL, Los datos que quiero almacenar en la tabla son de textbox,label,combobox y tambien datos de el datagridview mi problema es que cuando son varias filas en el datagridview digamos 3, solo se almacena la primera fila y se repite 3 veces, Estoy usando c# en 3 capas.El código

```html
                 for (int i = 0; i < dgvUsuarios.RowCount; i++)
                    {
                            string codUser = Convert.ToString(UserLoginCache.idUser);
                            string idProd = dgvUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                            string preVent = dgvUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                            string cant = dgvUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                            string subTot = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(preVent) * Convert.ToDecimal(cant));
                            string igv = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(subTot) * 18 / 100);
                            string total = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(igv) + Convert.ToDecimal(subTot));

                            objetoCN.InsertarVen(bf, label4.Text, lblCorrelativo.Text, textBox1.Text, lblcodClie.Text, idProd, codUser, cmbMedio.Text, preVent, cant, subTot, igv, total);
                        
                    }
```

de la capa presentación es el siguiente

Comment: Así a vote pronto, no entiendo lo de poner dos `for`recorriendo las mismas filas, además no usas en ningún momento las variables de iteración `i` ni `a`. Lo que si esta claro es porque solo coge los datos de una fila, y es porque estas usando la fila seleccionada en cada iteración del bucle y supongo que en lugar de repetirse 3 veces se repetirá 9 veces.

Comment: si entiendo lo del for adicional fue un error , pero como hago para que guarde cada fila en vez que solo la primera donde puedo usar las variables de iteracion en el InsertarVen, supongo que lo  que tengo que hacer es que mientras la variable de iteracion aumente en cada posición almacenar datos pero n ose como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Vale voy a escribirte una respuesta mas elaborada para guiarte mejor.

Por un lado quieres recorrer las `Rows` de tu `Datagrid`, es por ello que estas usando un bucle `for`. Lo que no haces es acceder a cada una de las distintas filas, para ello usas la variable de iteración `i` y para acceder a cada fila se haría:

```
dgvUsuarios.Rows[i] //De esta forma accedes a la fila en la posición i.
```

De tal forma que tu código quedaría como sigue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvUsuarios.RowCount; i++)
{
        string codUser = Convert.ToString(UserLoginCache.idUser); //Este variable no tiene mucho sentido que esté dentro del for ya que no cambia en cada iteración
        string idProd = dgvUsuarios.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string preVent = dgvUsuarios.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string cant = dgvUsuarios.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string subTot = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(preVent) * Convert.ToDecimal(cant)); 
        string igv = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(subTot) * 18 / 100);
        string total = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(igv) + Convert.ToDecimal(subTot));

        objetoCN.InsertarVen(bf, label4.Text, lblCorrelativo.Text, textBox1.Text, lblcodClie.Text, idProd, codUser, cmbMedio.Text, preVent, cant, subTot, igv, total);

}
```

Espero que te quede un poco mas claro y te pueda ayudar a aclarar ideas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda en serio poniéndolo así es muy simple , ya me funciono pero me sale una excepción System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto, la linea de codigo que me señala es esta :

string idProd = dgvUsuarios.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

ahora bien si me guarda normal pero me sale ese mensaje antes de guardar , disculpa la molestia tendrías alguna sugerencia ? pensé que el try catch  lo controlaba pero no

Comment: Ese error te da seguramente porque la celda no tiene valor valor. Puede que tengas alguna fila vacía en el datagrid o algo similar.

Comment: Si acabo de revisar y para el programa las 3 columnas que estoy extrayendo del datagridview supuesta mente están vacías pero no entiendo porque guarda normal